# Selenium server max firefox instances

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid2

I have one server with 32 Gb RAM and I want run 70 firefox instances in parallel. I try simple selenium server config like this:

```
java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar -port 4444 -maxSession 100 -DPOOL_MAX=1024 -trustAllSSLCertificates
```

But when i run 70 tests in parallel PHP selenium webdriver return error:

```
exception 'WebDriverCurlException' with message 'Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"firefox_profile":"....","browserName":"firefox","javascriptEnabled":true}}

Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received' in /app/vendors/SeleniumWebdriver/WebDriverExceptions.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendors/SeleniumWebdriver/remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php(213): WebDriverException::throwException(-1, 'Curl error thro...', Array)
#1 /app/vendors/SeleniumWebdriver/remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(74): HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(WebDriverCommand))
```

then i try create selenium grid 2 with one hub and two nodes but it is still not working (i get same error). Probably i must set DPOOL_MAX more than 1024?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do though? Load test your server? If so, there are much better tools out there to use than Selenium and you should rethink your approach IMO

Comment: No, i am using it for parsing sites and get it screenshot. So, my architecture used a 70 of PHP Gearman workers and this workers call selenium server.